# Rest Interface for MySQL DB with ACL

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-services, rest

99% of what REST API's do is serve as a controlled interface between client and DB, and yet I can't for the life of me find any libraries that do just that.

All libraries focus on providing a REST interface to the developer, who then sets up the communication with the database. It seems like a no-brainer to me to create a library that already interfaces with the database, and all the developer needs to do is define some ACL rules and plug in some logic here or there.

So, before I continue and put my thoughts into actions by actually creating this sort of library, may I just ask anyone with knowledge on the subject; has anyone implemented anything like this yet? Will I be re-inventing the wheel?

I'm talking strictly about a PHP based solutions by the way, I have nothing against other languages, PHP is simply my cup of tea. But for that matter, I haven't found any implementations in other languages either.

And in case my explanation doesn't make it very clear, this is essentially what I'd want:

```
<?php

class post_controller extends controller {

    protected static $config = array(
        'select'        => true,
        'insert'        => true,
        'update'        => true,
        'delete'        => false,

        'fields'            => array(
            'id'        => array(
                'select'    => true,
                'update'    => false
            ),
            'name'      => array(
                'select'    => true,
                'update'    => true
            ),
            'content'   => array(
                'select'    => true,
                'update'    => true
            )
        )
    );

    /**
     * GET, POST, DELETE are implemented already by the parent controller
     * Just overriding PUT to modify the content entry
     */
    function put($data) {
        $data->content = htmlentities($data);
        return parent::put($data);
    }

}

?>
```

Thanks in advance for anyone giving their input and apologies if this is not a proper Stackoverflow question.

Edit:

To clarify, this type of service would be for specific use-cases, I don't imagine it to be a type of thing that anyone can use for any type of web service.

Comment: by the time you've specified acls and "a little bit of logic", you've basically built a framework, and don't need this mythical rest-in-a-box system. Check out [amfphp](http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/) for how a Flash remoting "rest" api looks like. It's not as easy as you want it to be.

Comment: Flash remoting? I'm not talking about AMF at all. I've build many REST (and AMF) interfaces myself and know very well that it's not as fast as it could be. I fear you may be miss-understanding my proposal/question.

Comment: If you are looking for a stateless, uniform interface to a database when may I suggest SQL.  It is designed to do exactly that.  REST is not intended to expose databases over the wire, which is why experienced REST developers have not built a framework to do such a thing.

Comment: REST is just a protocol, my suggestion isn't protocol specific. The same goes for MySQL in this case. What I'm suggesting is a configurable web service that interfaces with a database and lets you set ACL's as well as plugin to automated methods to extend upon the default behaviour. Meaning a big part of the work you do over and over again when creating web services is already done for you. If this is not something that appeals to you that's fine, but being an experienced REST developer myself I respectfully disagree with your reasoning as to why such a solution does not seem to exist yet.

Comment: This is not a great idea IMO. Exposing your database schema via REST is just a security nightmare, even if the REST itself is validated, it could provide useful info for holes elsewhere on the site. Ask yourself why you want to expose DB via REST? Is it because you really think its a great idea, or because you want to avoid the trouble of writing a middleware layer?

Comment: What I'm proposing IS a middleware layer, which already connects to the DB, leaving you to configure it as you see fit. You can disallow access to fields or tables all-together or plug in additional security measures where necessary. Really the security implications are no different then in any other scenario, if anything it can only be more secure since all DB communication with the outside is centralized. At the end of the day it's up to the developer to know how to make your service secure, no matter what technology you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have built a similar system for SOAP and must say it's very easy to do so. I haven't seen any prebuilt libraries that would help you do it (and I doubt they exist - see next paragraph), but it shouldn't take you more than a few hours to build your own solution (a day max - with testing and documentation writing included).

It is however a whole another question if you really want to do that. REST can be (mis)used for this purpose, but it is meant for manipulating resources. Records in a database only rarely have a one-to-one mapping with resources. If they do in your case (as they did in mine) then feel free to do it, otherwise it would be nicer to provide a proper REST API. Why expose your internal DB structure to the world? YMMV, of course.

Comment: REST is just a style, it wouldn't be a full RESTful implementation. Have you learned anything from your SOAP implementation that others should be mindful of? Thanks!

Comment: Well, yes - that it was a bad idea to build it. ;) API would be much nicer if I built a custom solution each time, and it would be easier to do too. :)